# Safe to authenticate with ASP.NET MVC 3 site from Windows application?

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a basic ASP.NET MVC 3 site using Forms authentication, which will be internet-facing.

I also want to implement a Windows application, purely for intranet usage, which will allow users to maintain various aspects of the ASP.NET user database (it has additional tables and fields beyond the stock schema).

My initial thoughts are that I could do this by having various actions in my controller classes, into which I could pass a dedicated username/password and then within each action method validate those credentials using Membership.ValidateUser() .

I realise I could use mixed-mode authentication with Windows authentication for the intranet part but this seems to me like a lot of unnecessary faffing since the intranet users won't be using a browser to do this.

The Windows application will running on the corporate intranet and will be accessing those MVC 3 actions on the website via internal HTTP requests using this dedicated username/password in the query string.

Question: Is this safe enough?

Answer (score 0):

Hi we have a similar situation, we chose to build the management interface into the web application and using ASP_NET Roles to give access to it.

Otherwise (not sure how it works) but in the properties of a Windows Forms project you have the option of using forms authentication, this could  possibly be a better solution.

Comment: Yeah, that's the *logical* way to do it :) 

The issue is that I'm trying to marry a back-end ERP system with its own authentication system into the website authentication system. I basically want to customise the ERP side so that users created there automatically get logins created on the website.